# In a solid state laser does increasing the temperature increase the band gap voltage in a continuous manner or in discrete steps?

Tags: laser

Specifically with mode hopping, does the band gap voltage and I suppose the forward voltage change in a continuous manner with increasing temperature or when mode hopping occurs, does the band gap voltage increase in a discontinuous manner as well.

Answer (score -1):

I have done some reading and here's an answer to the question.

In mode hopping the wavelength can change nearly instantaneously. So the band gap voltage can change at the same rate, nearly instantaneously.

[image]